# How to multiply a benchmark

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

Say I have a benchmark result like so:

```
0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.020197)
```

I'm creating this with something like

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { run_a_method() }
end
```

This represents the time required to call a method `foo` one time.

I want to produce a benchmark which shows the result of running `foo` 3 times, but only requires calling the method once.

This can be done by simply multiplying the values in the first benchmark by 3.

Is there any way to do this?

### Edit

I'm not really appreciating the comments that this is "not a correct benchmark". I recognize that it is more accurate to run it multiple times, but these are  resource-intensive tests and I am simply projecting an expected time frame for multiple runs.

In other words, my use-case is just to create an expectation for the multiple-run time, not a wholly accurate one.

Comment: Its context has not been explained in detail, here no one is a mind reader. All I'm trying is to give it a correct approach. I believe that you have been disrespectful to downvote against for my answer

Comment: For your initial question, we just pointed out that your statement, to produce a benchmark to show result of running `foo` 3 times by actually only calling the method once and just multiplying it by 3 is just plain wrong. If you had already known it, and wanted a not so accurate result, then that should have been specified before hand. like in your edit now.

Comment: Without proper explanation, all we can assume from the information you provide is that you were trying to do something wrong, and all we tried to do was help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

Initially I tried the following:

```
report = Benchmark.bm do |x|  
  x.report { sleep.0.5 }
end
# => report is an array with     
#    1 element

report * 2
# => shows an array with 2 elements
#    (the first is duplicated)
```

But I eventually thought to try

```
report[0] * 2
```

which had the intended effect of doubling the values in the benchmark.

For example, if the `report` variable points to

```
[#<Benchmark::Tms:0x0055fcba149030
@label="", 
@real=0.5001437529999748, 
@cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, 
@stime=0.0, @utime=0.0, @total=0.0>]
```

The running `puts (report[0] * 2)` shows

```
  0.000000   0.000000   
0.000000 (  1.000288)
=> nil
```

which is the multiplied value I was going for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with extrapolating, as you suggest, is that it compounds any errors you've got. Running N rounds of a single benchmark tends to even out any irregularities. Running 1 round and multiplying by N actually amplifies any irregularities.

So the short answer is you can't. You need to run multiple tests to get a better idea of performance. If these tests take a long time to run you either have to eat the cost or find ways of running them more quickly, or in parallel somehow.