# Prevent output while using Ruby Benchmark

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to compare the [touch](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-touch) method that Rake includes to shelling out to the system touch.

Each operation is sending output to stdout:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'rake'

n = 3
result = Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("sh:") do
    n.times { sh "touch foo.txt" }
  end
  x.report("touch:") do
    n.times { touch "bar.txt" }
  end
end
```

result:

```
user     system      total        real
sh:touch foo.txt
touch foo.txt
touch foo.txt
  0.000000   0.010000   0.030000 (  0.024775)
touch:touch bar.txt
touch bar.txt
touch bar.txt
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000412)
```

What I'd like is:

```
user     system      total        real
sh:touch foo.txt
  0.000000   0.010000   0.030000 (  0.024775)
touch:touch bar.txt
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000412)
```

Or something else that only has the results.

I read in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969333/run-benchmark-but-dont-print-the-result) to use `Benchmark.measure` but the following also doesn't work:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'rake'

n = 3
result = Benchmark.measure do 
  n.times { sh "touch foo.txt" }
end

puts result
```

result:

```
touch foo.txt
touch foo.txt
touch foo.txt
  0.000000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.022931)
```

How do I benchmark `sh` and `touch` but prevent output from going to stdout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the source of `sh`](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/sh) it seems it accepts `verbose` as an option so the right invocation for you should be:

```
sh "touch foo.txt", verbose: false
```

The same [can be said of `touch`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/FileUtils/touch/class):

```
touch "bar.txt", verbose: false
```

It seems the docs don't mention these options at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect `$stdout`

See this example

```
puts 1
original_stdout = $stdout
$stdout = open("/dev/null", "w")
puts 2
$stdout = original_stdout
puts 3
```

Which prints

```
1
3
```

But does not print `2`

Comment: Why the downvote? Please comment so I can improve the answer.